# How can I get a list of all mobile devices from admin.google.com via the Google directory api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, mobile-devices

I'm trying to get a list of all mobile devices from [G Suite Admin](https://admin.google.com/ac/devices/list?category=mobile) in a python script using [guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices). But in response, I only get a list of devices owned by users, not the company. I marked the device's return in green on the screenshot. [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFn2t.jpg)

Previously, I created a project in Google Cloud, connected the admin SDK API to it, and created a service account. For the account I enabled data access delegation in the G Suite domain, which created an oauth 2.0 client ID for me.
Also in G Suite in the security settings I added access for this account to scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.mobile.

I don 't use the google library. Using it, I couldn 't bypass the proxy server.

I use the library [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to access the server. Here is an approximate algorithm of my actions:

- I create a JWT using the library [jwt](https://pypi.org/project/jwt/).  I use the "sub" parameter to specify an account in Google admin. The account I use has administrator rights.
- Using JWT I get a google access token.
- Using the access token I get a list of devices according to the instructions https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list.

But I don't get all the necessary devices. How can I get devices that are owned by an organization?

Answer (score 0):

### With `https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list` you can only see devices assigned to an account:

The one you specify with the paramter `customerId` - see [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list).

Unfortunately the API does not have an endpoint to list devices belonging to the company, i.e. unassigned devices.